# How Does Rails Routes Handle Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, controller, routes

I have a controller action that takes a cart of items and and if the purchase is successful runs this action:

```
redirect_to "/delist/#{session[:pending_purchase]}"
```

Where :pending_purchase is an array of item ID numbers (of items that got added to the cart), and delist removes said item(s) from the store so that they are no longer available for purchase.

My question is: can the redirect_to method handle an array? Is there a way to set this up in my routes so it passes the array to the delist controller? Or is there a better way to do this all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. `redirect_to` can only handle strings, named url helpers, and instance variables which will be turned to named url.

Long answer: Incorrect action in your case.

You are cooking it wrong to put ids in url in this case. You can simply redirect to the cart url again. The items have been deleted from cart, so the new cart shows updated items. Why need items ids in url?

Comment: My cart creates line items that are not associated with the product listing itself. The delist conrtoller has nothing to do with the cart really. The delist controller just tracks what products ID's the line items are associated with when they are added to the cart. So when the purchase is made it remove the items from my active inventory. The delist controller actually uses an API to reach out to another ecommerce store and removes it from there too so my inventories stay synced up.

Comment: @Davey, maybe I have not understood your situation fully. But, according to your points on comment, couldn't you create a new column in Cart model, serialize it to save the ids? That should be much simpler.

Comment: Yeah, that would make a lot more sense. Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely implement that!